# Column-view options in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, pantheon

Good morning everyone,

I would like the "Column view" option, which is not avaible for nautilus.
So I found that Pantheon-files has this option.

But i am trying so bad to install it and there Ubuntu seems not to be willing to help.

All help I can find on internet is based on previous ubuntus, thus I guess it is not really helping.
I add a picture of what I get.

BytheWay, if there is any other options to get column view (like finder of macOS) instead of pantheon-files, it will be very welcomed.

The trick is that needs to be for ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you!

[image: sources.list sends me some error]

Comment: The system is telling you that those two PPAs are not compatible with your release of Ubuntu. Delete both PPAs from your sources.

Comment: Hmmmm How can I delete those ppa's?  By the way, what is a ppa?

Comment: Use the Search box at the top of the page to look up each error. These questions have been answered many times.

Comment: It has been answered for other ubuntus (17, 16 etc) but not for this one. And it seems that other had other kind of troubles. And, I followed the other answers and I could not